# Este es un algoritmo para ordenar los elementos numericos de un array

Tags: array, c, elementos

Hice una función cuya esencia es la de ordenar, consiste en un for anidado que evalúa el primer índice con los índices restantes, al final del primer ciclo el arreglo tiene que terminar con el mayor en el primer índice del arreglo y así sucesivamente, al final del segundo ciclo el mayor queda en el segundo índice, etc

El segundo for anidado al primero lo inicialicé con relación al primero, igualando a i el contador j del segundo array cada que empieza la evaluación de un índice con el resto de índices como dije al principio y aparte le sumo 1 para evitar la comparación de los mismos índices.

Nomás quiero saber si no es una mala practica de programación definir el contador de un for con la variable de un contador de otro for gracias, les dejo mi código para que lo chequen:

```
void ordenDecreciente(int ina[],int longi1)
{
    int aux[5];
    
    int i=0, j=0, val1=0, val2=0;

    for (i=0; i<longi1; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<longi1; j++)
        {   
            val1=ina[i];
            val2=ina[j];
            printf("\n %i, %i",i,j);

            if (val1<val2)
                {
                    aux[i]=ina[i];
                    ina[i]=ina[j];
                    ina[j]=aux[i];
                }
        }   
    }

    printf("\n %i", ina[0]);
    printf("\n %i", ina[1]);
    printf("\n %i", ina[2]);
    printf("\n %i", ina[3]);
    printf("\n %i", ina[4]);
}
```

Comment: No es una mala practica de programación definir el contador de un `for` con la variable de un contador de otro `for`.

Comment: Tu algoritmo es básicamente el conocido como _bubble-sort_ ([ordenamiento de burbuja](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja)), y es perfectamente válido (aunque no el más rápido).